# Callback function ajax, JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

```
const getData = (method, url, print) => {
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    ajax.open(method, url)
    ajax.send();

    ajax.onload = function(){
        const result = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText)
        print(result)
    }
}

const print = () => {
    result.map((item) => {
        console.log(item.title)
    })
}


getData('GET', 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', print)
```

but the output is, "ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined"
can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: What environment your JavaScript executed? With a browser? node.js? JsShell? Rhino?

Comment: I use a node to execute the code

Comment: So, node.js is not a browser. XMLHttpRequest is only available in browsers. You may need some other way to do a fetch as others described in their answers. Btw, your print function failed to receive the result argument.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` is a global variable provided by browser JS runtimes.

If you are getting a reference error then you aren't running your code in a browser and need to find an alternative (e.g. if you are using Node.js you can install [the `axios` module from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)).

Comment: @Lain — It's 2020, the odds of anybody trying to write code using IE 6 are miniscule.